# How to search in all django models with Haystack and Whoosh?

Tags: django, search, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm using django and haystack with whoosh and I have several questions about them:

1) When I attempt to search smth I should select all models which has indexed in whoosh. How can I set system to find values everywhere (on all models)?

2) I have search input box but it doesn't work with haystack urls. So my template (I'm using bootstrap):

```
<form  method="get" action="/search/" class="navbar-search pull-left">
   <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

And I have search url like in tutorial:

```
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

How say this form to start search immidiately and sends data to haystack?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create RealTimeSearchIndex classes in your search_index.py file in the project root, and register these indexes with haystack.

Then you need to reindex your data using the haystack `manage.py reindex` command.

Then you need to provide a template for the search page that haystack will generate.

Keep reading the docs, it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

For part 2,

since haystack uses ?q= to get queries, you should put name="q" into the input field,

```
<form  method="get" action="/search/" class="navbar-search pull-left">
    <input name="q" type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

For part 1,

you can put in search_indexes.py into each model folder. Not sure if there is more efficient method. You can use ModelSearchView if you want to give users a choice to search which models.